# Display a div when post has a certain tag

Tags: javascript, conditional-tags

I'm currently developing a wordpress blog site but I think this question maybe a bit of JS magic at the same time so put it here rather than Wordpress Development.

I'm looking to create a post and have a certain div display on the post when a tag criteria is met e.g. if I tag a post with 'crazy css trick' I'm looking to display a badge on the post with 'Crazy CSS tricks' written on it. But also still allowing me to tag the post with multiple tags not just 1.

(This is similar to a 'featured' post and displaying a 'Featured' badge on the post)

This is Wordpress
Would love to have this in the main loop.
TL;DR

Wordpress Site
Allowing Multiple Tags
Displaying a certain tag on the post in the form of a badge
Needs to be in main loop.
A site which does similar to this is VEVO which you can see here http://www.vevo.com/ on their slideshow they have 'Exclusive' 'Original Show' Etc.

Any help would be great, tried a few ways but they seem to either do 'if' statements for every post and not exactly great performance wise.

Thanks

Comment: The VEVO website seems to use more of a post category, then a post tag. I am not sure I follow your entire question. You want to be able to display the tag as a badge? But only one tag, not all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a simple conditional and check if the post has a term using [`has_term()`:](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term)

[`has_term( $term, $taxonomy, $post );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term)

Pass in your Term Slug, the taxonomy ( which sounds like you're using `post_tag` and the post object, no javascript needed.

```
<?php if( has_term( 'term_slug', 'post_tag', $post ) : ?>

    <div>
        Show your div here!
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Apologies for this silly comment but how would I go about showing the div for posts tagged as 'CSS Trick'? Can you leave fields blank? or does it need custom taxonomy?

Comment: You don't need a custom taxonomy. If you're using the built in posts you already have 2 taxonomies: `category` ( hierarchical categories ) and `post_tag` which is the one you enter on the fly ( you can't assign a parent to these ). So if we assume your title is `CSS Trick` then the slug would be `css-trick` and you would just add that in the place of `term_slug` in my code. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Hmm does there need to be a term_slug? As I just essentially want to place in a certain tag then make the div appear when it has that certain tag. (Apologies starting on Wordpress and can't seem to grasp this concept!)